# Populando Cidades/Bairros em jQuery com campos em Array

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){

         $("select[name=cidade]").change(function(){
            $("select[name=bairro]").html('<option value="0">Carregando...</option>');

            $.post("bairros.ajax.php",
                  {cidade:$(this).val()},
                  function(valor){
                     $("select[name=bairro]").html(valor);
                  }
                  )

         })
      })

</script>
```

E o HTML

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <select name="cidade">
       <option value="0">Escolha uma Cidade</option>
        <?php
         mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
         mysql_select_db("jcentregas");

         $sql = "SELECT * FROM cidade ORDER BY cidade ASC";
         $qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
         while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['idCidade'].'">'.$ln['cidade'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>

    </select>

    <select name="bairro">
       <option value="0" disabled="disabled">Escolha uma cidade Primeiro</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

bairros.ajax.php

```
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("jcentregas");

$cidade = $_POST['cidade'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bairro WHERE idCidade = '$cidade' ORDER BY bairro ASC";
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($qr) == 0){
   echo  '<option value="0">'.$_POST['cidade']."->".htmlentities('Não bairros nesta cidade').'</option>';

}else{
   while($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)){
      echo '<option value="'.$ln['idBairro'].'">'.$ln['bairro'].'</option>';
   }
}
```

Teoricamente ele funciona perfeitamente.
Porém, eu gostaria que o nome dos campos fossem em array
porque são várias cidades e vários bairros que podem ser selecionados
exemplo:

Nesta imagem, eu posso adicionar vários campos com o mesmo nome e repassar-los na array... dá pra fazer isto com as cidades/bairros no jquery e html acima?
[image]

Comment: Se eu entendi direito o que você necessita é o `$_POST` em formato de array. Para isto você tera que deixar o nome dos campos dinâmico. Exemplo : `<select name="tr[0][cidade]"></select>`. onde o `0` seria um `contador` de `tr's`.

Comment: Exatamente guilherme, Mas se eu trocar o nome do campo por um nome em array[] o jquery não irá buscar os bairros..... e é justamente essa a minha dúvida. :(

Comment: fiz rapidamente, vais ter de adaptar.
http://jsfiddle.net/8zaadera/

Comment: Usei o jQuery 1.7.2, pois é o que uso no trabalho, se quiser usar o 1.11 tera de adaptar para `.on('change', function(){ /* code */})`

Comment: Entendi... mas ali ele busca os resultados do select anterior... dá pra alterar? não entendo muito de js.

Comment: ah ok, eu pressupus que você já saberia o que fazer, mas sim você pode utilizar esta funcao dento do seu `post`, assim http://jsfiddle.net/8zaadera/2/

Comment: Atualmente eu passo os parâmetros dessa forma:
<select class="input-small" name="cham_bairro[]" id="cham_bairro[]" style="width: 150px;">

Comment: creio que deste jeito não esteja incorreto, só torna a leitura um pouco mais complexa.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25120/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-guilherme-lautert).